# jQuery .append(html) command appending incorrectly

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, jquery

I am using a jQuery/Ajax call to append a partial view to a table. When the page loads, the partial view is created correctly. However, once the use attempts to append another item to the table, the formatting is incorrect despite the exact same partial view being used.

Here is the table. When this loads, the items are loaded onto the page correctly as the picture below illustrates:

```
     <table id="fixedRows">
     <thead>
        <tr>
           <th>State Code</th>
           <th>Agent ID</th>
           <th></th>
           <th></th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>    
    @foreach (var item in Model.BankListAgentId)
    {                    
        if (!String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(item.AgentId) && item.FixedOrVariable.Equals("F"))
        {
            @Html.EditorFor(model => item, "FixedPartialView")                     
        }
    }
</tbody>
</table>
<br />
<a href="#" class="addFixed">Add Another</a>
```

[image]

Once you click the `Add another` link, this jQuery/Ajax call is activiated

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {

        $(".addFixed").click(function () {
            //alert('test');
            event.preventDefault();        
            $.ajax({
                url: '@Url.Action("BlankFixedRow", "BankListMaster")',
                cache: false,
                success: function (html) { $("#fixedRows").append(html); }
            });
        });

        $("#addVariable").click(function () {
            event.preventDefault();
            $.ajax({
                url: '@Url.Action("BlankFixedRow", "BankListMaster")',
                cache: false,
                success: function (html) { $("#variableRows").append(html); }
            });
        });

    });


</script>
```

That jQuery calls this method from the controller

```
    public ViewResult BlankFixedRow()
    {
        SelectList tmpList = new SelectList(new[] { "AL", "AK", "AS", "AZ", "AR", "CA", "CO", "CT", "DE", "DC", "FM", "FL", "GA", "GU", "HI", "ID", "IL", "IN", "IA", "KS", "KY", "LA", "ME", "MH", "MD", "MA", "MI", "MN", "MS", "MO", "MT", "NE", "NV", "NH", "NJ", "NA", "NM", "NY", "NC", "ND", "MP", "OH", "OK", "OR", "PW", "PA", "PR", "RI", "SC", "SD", "TN", "TX", "UT", "US", "VT", "VI", "VA", "WA", "WV", "WI", "WY" });
        ViewBag.StateCodeList = tmpList;

        return View("FixedPartialView", new BankListAgentId());
    }
```

Which calls this partial view
EDIT(a couple people noticed the `id` tag missing from the `<tr>`, this was just a copy/paste error for this post, the actual code has the `id` tag)

```
    @model Monet.Models.BankListAgentId

@{
    Layout = null;
}
    @using (Html.BeginCollectionItem("BankListAgentId"))
    {
        <tr id="item-@Model.AgentId">
            <td>
                @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.StateCode,
                    (SelectList)ViewBag.StateCodeList, Model.StateCode)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.AgentId)
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.AgentId)
            </td>
            <td>
                <a href="#" class="deleteRow">delete</a>
            </td>
            @*<td><a href="#" onclick="$('#item-@Model.AgentId').parent().remove();" style="float:right;">Delete</a></td>*@
        </tr>
    }
```

This is the same partial view that is called when the page first loads, which part of why I'm confused that the end result after hitting the `Add another` link turns out looking like this

[image]

EDIT

If you hit the `Add another` link twice, this is the result

[image]

EDIT

I've tried the following jQuery `sucess` commands with no luck

```
success: function (html) { $("#fixedRows > tbody:last").append(html); }
success: function (html) { $("#fixedRows tr:last").after(html); }
success: function (html) { $("#fixedRows  > tbody").append(html); }
```

Here is the HTML that is rendered after the `Add another` link is clicked. I included the opening `<form>` tag for the form below it to show that the new rows are nowhere to be found.

```
<form action="/BankListMaster/Edit/11" method="post">        
    <fieldset>
        <legend>Stat(s) Fixed</legend>
        <table id="fixedRows">
            <tr>
                <th>State Code</th>
                <th>Agent ID</th>
                <th></th>
                <th></th>
            </tr>

            <tr id="item-1164998320">
                <td>
                    <select id="item_StateCode" name="item.StateCode"><option value="">HI</option>
                        <option>AL</option>
                        ..
                        <option>WY</option>
                    </select>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <input class="text-box single-line" id="item_AgentId" name="item.AgentId" type="text" value="1164998320" />
                    <span class="field-validation-valid" data-valmsg-for="item.AgentId" data-valmsg-replace="true"></span>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <a href="#" class="deleteRow">delete</a>
                </td>
            </tr>    
            <tr id="item-1164998219">
                <td>
                    <select id="item_StateCode" name="item.StateCode">
                        <option value="">HI</option>
                        <option>AL</option>
                        ..
                        <option>WY</option>
                    </select>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <input class="text-box single-line" id="item_AgentId" name="item.AgentId" type="text" value="1164998219" />
                    <span class="field-validation-valid" data-valmsg-for="item.AgentId" data-valmsg-replace="true"></span>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <a href="#" class="deleteRow">delete</a>
                </td>
            </tr>    
            <tr id="item-0352926603">
                <td>
                    <select id="item_StateCode" name="item.StateCode">
                        <option value="">GA</option>
                        <option>AL</option>
                        ..
                        <option>WY</option>
                    </select>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <input class="text-box single-line" id="item_AgentId" name="item.AgentId" type="text" value="0352926603" />
                    <span class="field-validation-valid" data-valmsg-for="item.AgentId" data-valmsg-replace="true"></span>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <a href="#" class="deleteRow">delete</a>
                </td>
            </tr>            
        </table>
        <br />
        <a href="#" class="addFixed">Add Another</a>
    </fieldset>
</form>     
<a href="#" class="addFixed">Add Another</a>
<form action="/BankListMaster/Edit/11" method="post">
```

EDIT

Here is a screen shot of the table in Chrome's debugger after the `Add Another` link is clicked. As you can see, the data pulled from the table is loaded properly in respective `<tr>` tags, however the empty row (which is sent via the same partial view as the rest) doesn't have any of the same table elements. The screen shot below that shows Response, however, which does include the `<tr>` tags

[image]
[image]

EDIT

I put a `console.log(html)` line in the `success` Ajax function so it now reads

```
            success: function (html) {
                console.log(html);
                $("#fixedRows > tbody").append(html);
            }
```

Here is the console output (state edited for readability)

```
<input type="hidden" name="BankListAgentId.index" autocomplete="off" value="3f7e0a92-8f20-4350-a188-0725919f9558" />
        <tr>
            <td>
                <select id="BankListAgentId_3f7e0a92-8f20-4350-a188-0725919f9558__StateCode" name="BankListAgentId[3f7e0a92-8f20-4350-a188-0725919f9558].StateCode">
                    <option>AL</option>
                    ..
                    <option>WY</option>
                </select>
            </td>
            <td>
                <input class="text-box single-line" id="BankListAgentId_3f7e0a92-8f20-4350-a188-0725919f9558__AgentId" name="BankListAgentId[3f7e0a92-8f20-4350-a188-0725919f9558].AgentId" type="text" value="" />                 
            </td>
            <td>
                <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="deleteRow">delete</a>
            </td>               
        </tr>
```

Comment: Where is your element with the `id` #variableRows? It's not in your HTML.

Comment: There are two tables that are identical to each other, I left it out since I'm just working on fixed the first one at the moment. The current issues are specific to the `#fixedRows` table.

Comment: It may be that your `<tr>` and `<td>` are getting stripped before you append.  What does the raw HTML returned by the AJAX call look like?

Comment: Also, your partial is generating all the `<tr>`s with the `id` of "1".  You cannot have duplicate `id`s within a document.

Comment: Sorry, the `<tr>` id is in there from something i was debugging. I'll remove that.

Comment: HTML added per request

Comment: Table header defines four columns, ajax/partial returning 3.

Comment: can you share the returned html string from ajax request

Comment: @ArunPJohny: added the `html` return item to the post.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What a complete nightmare...

First off, the HTML that was being returned as viewable in Chrome's debugger was fine, however when I clicked on "View Source" for the page, I could not see anything but what was originally loaded. After finding [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8598836/jquery-dom-changes-not-appearing-in-view-source), I found that this is normal. I then used [this Chrome add-on](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/current-source-code/ljcogemcngolehdjglgiaphnmggiacca/related?hl=en) to finally see that the `<tr>` and `<td>` tags were being stripped out. By simply adding an opening and closing tag to the append statement, I got the returned items to append to the table.

```
    $(".addFixed").click(function () {
        $.ajax({
            url: '@Url.Action("BlankFixedRow", "BankListMaster")',
            dataType: 'html',
            cache: false,
            success: function (html) {
                $("#fixedRows > tbody").append('<tr>' + html + '</tr>');
            }
        });
    });
```

Comment: Why is the TR and TD being removed, I'm having similar issues and can't find the reason.

Comment: Apparently, browsers don't like you trying to append something that isn't a `<tr>` to a `<tbody>` or `<table>`  and will strip out all `<tr>` and `<td>` tags when inserting the markup into the DOM. The solution is to put the `using (Html.BeginCollectionItem())` inside the `<tr>` tags, wrapping the `<td>`s.

Answer (score 1):

I see a few things here. You're referencing `<tbody>` in some of your code but I don't see it anywhere in the page. So first I would suggest using `<thead>` and `<tbody>`. In your partial view I see `<tr "item-@Model.AgentId">` which should have an id.

You should also remove the onclick handler and the delete button and put that in with the rest of your JavaScript. Set a class on your delete links instead.

For links that don't need urls and are only used for attaching JavaScript handlers, I recommend using `href="javascript:void(0)"` as this would prevent the browser from doing anything special with `href="#"` so then you'll be able to remove the calls to `preventDefault()`.

As to the source of your problem, `$("#fixedRows tbody").append(html)` is the code you want so no need to try `after()`. It looks like your html is getting stripped. Try setting the `dataType` attribute in the `$.ajax()` call to `html`.

Comment: Edited the HTML to show the `<thead>` and `<tbody>` tags, still no luck. Did the same with the `dataType` and didn't see any different results.