# Write something inside input id tag with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this:

```
<input name="input_2" id="input_1_2" type="text" value="" class="medium" tabindex="1">
```

And i want to jquery write this in my html code:

```
<input name="input_2" id="input_1_2" onblur="myFunction()" type="text" value="" class="medium" tabindex="1">
```

With this:

```
$('#input_1_2').blur(function(){myFunction();});
```

It's working, but if you see the html code, the `onblur="myFunction()"` is nothing on the html code, and I would like that written on my html code with jquery. (need to be written in jquery or javascript).

Thanks for help!

Comment: Why do you need it to appear inline?

Comment: because i'll get the code of generated html and write in a file.

Comment: And then, I'm gonna use the generated code where i dont wants to load jquery library, only a little javascript myFunciton with -1kb. Jquery minimal 91kb.

Comment: You would have to include the jQuery library to assign the function there in the first place with your jQuery code? What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$('#input_1_2').attr('onblur', 'myFunction()');`

I should also reference the fact that jQuery isn't changing the original source: [jQuery DOM changes not appearing in view source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8598836/jquery-dom-changes-not-appearing-in-view-source)

Comment: Working =)
Thank you! I tried to find a solution here, Google, and all, but maybe i'm trying with bad words. Really thanks! I'm going to give a point to you if i can. I believe new users cant give points, but if i can i'll.

Answer (score 1):

You can write a handler to call that function with jQuery

```
$("#input_1_2").blur(myFunction);
```

Comment: Yes, its work, but i wants to the onblur="myFuncion()" written on the html code. When you see the html code, there is no onblur="xx" on the input.