# Dynamicly generated fields does not work with validator(HTM5)

Tags: html, field, validation, dynamically-generated

I have a dynamic generated form which comes with three textboxes generated by javascript (there is no issues with thoses ones) but when it displayed and I add a new textbox as the same way as the three ones, the validator detects only the three textboxes and not the new ones which cames after that the page is displayed.

I think that the form have to be refreshed.
Do you have any idea?
Thanks a lot.

Comment: This sounds like an issue of the DOM getting updated by not the page (View Source). Could you describe your code a little more? Specifically, when the 3 (working) text inputs are added and when the 1 (failing) text input is added.

Comment: I use the append function to add them in the form. (All of them) the three first ones are added while the page is loaded and the last one when I click on a button,I created a function which do that.

Comment: I am guessing if you "View Source" you'll see the first 3 text inputs but not the 4th.

Comment: See this for example - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8598836/jquery-dom-changes-not-appearing-in-view-source

Comment: When I hit F12 on chrome or firefox I see all of them with required attribute, but validator doesn't work on the fourth one.Thank you for your answer.