# Canonical tag value not appearing in page-source when using react-helmet

Tags: javascript, reactjs, canonical-link

I'm using react js and react-helmet to change the canonical tag values in the pages. But, it is not updating the value. Everywhere it is showing `https://www.example.com`, which is mentioned in my `index.php` file. I need to update the canonical link. I have earlier used jquery, but it didn't work out. It was updating in `element-inspector` and not in `page-source` but google was marking as duplicate pages.

I'm following https://github.com/nfl/react-helmet#server-usage

`canonical url code`

```
var newCanonicalUrl = "https://www.examle.com" + this.state.productUrl;
```

`inside render function`

```
return(<Helmet link = {[{"rel" : "canonical", "href" : {newCanonicalUrl}}]}>);
```

Answer (score 1):

This should do the trick:

```
link = {[
      { rel : 'canonical', href : newCanonicalUrl  }
]}
```

Comment: This does **not** answer the question in a useful way. _why_ do you believe this is the answer? _how_ does it work? Simply telling someone to _change their code_ without any context or meaning does not help them learn what they did wrong, and is also not useful for future readers.

Comment: @xameeramir check the DOM from inspect element, it should be present

Comment: @Sourabh Yes, the change reflects in the virtual DOM. It can be confirmed by inspecting the elements. However, the point of the question is all about page-source :)

Comment: @xameeramir, if you want the tags in source code then you have to do serverside rendering.

Comment: @Sourabh Oh, you talking about server-side rendering! Yeah then it will show up but I'm trying the client side.

Comment: @xameeramir https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8598836/jquery-dom-changes-not-appearing-in-view-source

Comment: Thank you @Sourabh The best thing about SO is it's the kind community :)