# How to show JavaScript output in page source code

Tags: javascript, html

In my web page i have use some JavaScript and its works fine and result shows what i needed. but when i go to  view page source i have seen only JavaScript code but can not see the output. Below is my code.

```
  var link = document.createElement('link');
  link.setAttribute('rel', 'canonical');
  link.setAttribute('href', location.protocol + '//' + location.host + location.pathname);
  document.head.appendChild(link);
</script>
```

This code woks good. when i click on "Inspect" on Google chrome i can see the its works. but an not see the output when i click on "View page source".

Can any one tell me how to show the output result in source code??

Comment: View page source is html page state rendered assuming no Javascript was run i.e. server sent raw html (if I'm not mistaken)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [jQuery DOM changes not appearing in view source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8598836/jquery-dom-changes-not-appearing-in-view-source)

Comment: Yes, "View Page Source" shows what was delivered from the server. Your JavaScript dynamically manipulates the Document Object Model (DOM), which can be viewed in the browser's dev tools.

Answer (score 2):

The `view page source` context menu option only show whats rendered from the server side. It does not contain whatever rendered on the client side.

If you want to see client side rendering you use `inspect element`.

Answer (score 1):

In Chrome, if you right-click the element and select "Inspect" the current DOM will be shown in the [developer tools Elements panel](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/open#elements). It will resemble HTML from "view page source," and include any changes you have made to the DOM via JS.

Answer (score 0):

`View Source` and `Inspect Element` are two browser features that allow developers to look at the HTML for a particular page.

**view** simply shows the HTML as it was delivered from the `web server` to our `browser or client side.`

When we inspect an element in Chrome developer tools (using the right-click menu or F12), we are looking at the current state of the DOM tree after:

HTML error correction by the browser or `HTML normalization` by the browser or `DOM manipulation by JavaScript`